DESFire ev1 write data command fails with 917D (PERMISSION_DENIED)
I am writing to an 8K MIFARE EV1 card.
Once the file is created, when I retrieve the file configuration (F5), it returns 00 00 EE EE 00 0F 00.
Then, I attempt to write to the card with the following command: 90 3B 00 00 0D 01 00 00 00 00 00 06 70 72 75 65 62 61 00, and it returns 91 7D.
I attempted to write data to a DESFire card using the specified write command parameters. I expected the data to be successfully written and immediately available for subsequent read operations. However, I encountered an Error during the write operation and the data not being saved to the card.

I assume you are tying to write to file number 01 in the application. Your want to write to the first position of the file so the offset is 0 = 000000h. The last parameter is the length of data you want to write. Both parameters for offset and length are LSB encoded, meaning you need to set the length of your data ("70 72 75 65 62 61"h = 6 bytes) as ""06 00 00" instead of "00 00 06". Btw. I'm using the command "0x3D" for writing on my tag, but "0x3B" may work as well.

I am indeed writing to file ID 01. I have modified the command as you suggested, and I am still getting the same result. The command is now in the form: 90 3B 00 00 0D 01 00 00 00 06 00 00 70 72 75 65 62 61 00.

Sorry for pointing to this again: writing to a Standard file on a DESFire tag is done with the command 0x3D" or "0x8D" (I always work with 3D). The command that you are using ("0x3B") is for writing a record. As the file is a Standard File the tag is refusing your command.

I changed it to the 3D command, and it’s working now. Thank you very much for your help.

According to Michael's instructions, the command is changed from 3B to 3D, and the order of the length bytes is modified, resulting in the following: 90 3D 00 00 0D 01 00 00 00 06 00 00 70 72 75 65 62 61 00.
With that, it works correctly now

I'm glad you got your app to work. The next fun will come up with any kind of authentication on the DESFire tag :-)

I've already had that problem LOL
